# CSS properties not working properly in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

some of my css styles like body background-image and align are not working properly with angular
although they are working perfectly when running the html file with same styles but I can't understand why

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, 
                                  rgba(125, 70, 184, 1) 0%,  
                                  rgba(100, 106, 195, 1) 35%,  
                                  rgba(55, 182, 216, 1) 100%);
}

table,
td {
  color: white;
}

.regContainer {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 80%;
}

.regContainer h1 {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(38, 33, 87);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.regContainer p {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(38, 33, 87);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.registartion-form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(44, 43, 105);
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.registartion-form input,
.registartion-form select,
.registartion-form textarea {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.registartion-form input:focus,
.registartion-form textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgb(228, 228, 228), -3px -3px 10px rgb(224, 224, 224);
}

.registartion-form .submit {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(96, 177, 45);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.registartion-form .submit:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="regCSS.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<div class="container">
    <div class="regContainer">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
  </div>
    <form name="registration" class="registartion-form" onsubmit="return formValidation()">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="your name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="your email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
          <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label></td>
          <td><input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="gender">Gender:</label></td>
          <td>Male: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
            Female: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="language">language</label></td>
          <td>
            <select name="language" id="language">
              <option value="">Select language</option>
              <option value="English">English</option>
              <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
              <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
              <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
              <option value="Russian">Russian</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="zipcode">Zip Code:</label></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="zipcode" id="zipcode"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="about">About:</label></td>
          <td><textarea name="about" id="about" placeholder="Write about yourself..."></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Register" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="regJS.js"></script>
</body>
```

most of it is working properly except for that I can't see the background gradient and the form is not centered on angular

how it should be:
[image: form html]

how it is on angular:
[image: form angular]

Comment: Without seeing relevant code it is impossible for us to help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I just added the code to the post, thank you.

Comment: In what file are you writing this css?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi signup.component.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some css selectors that, by default, cannot be targeted by a component.

So you have two ways:

1. Target those selector in the `style.scss` file.

Selectors such as `body`, `html`, `*`, etc (even the material ones or any library's style) by default cannot be targeted by the component's scope, so if you move them in your root css file (usually `style.scss`) you will see the properties applied.

2. Change the component's encapsulation.

If you want to change those selectors from the component's scope itself you can achieve that using `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-selector',
  templateUrl: './foo.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Using `ViewEncapsulation.None` means that the styles are applicable to any HTML element of the application regardless of their host Component.

Be aware that using no encapsulation can lead to some unwanted scenarios.
[More details here](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)